# jupyter error: can't view decision tree as png in random forest

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, decision-tree

I am trying to look at my decision tree in Jupyter Notebook. I have installed graphviz (in anaconda cmd prompt) and pydot.

```
#taking one tree from the forest and saving it as an image
#!pip install graphviz
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
#!pip install pydot
import pydot 

#pulling out one tree from the forest
tree = rf.estimators_[5]

#export one image to a dot file
feature_list = list(feature.columns)
export_graphviz(tree, out_file = 'tree.dot', feature_names = feature_list, 
           rounded = True, precision = 1)

#use dot file to create a graph
(graph, ) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree.dot')

#write graph to a png file
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

The last line runs successfully without any output.
I then run the code in anaconda command prompt:
`dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png` and get the error:
`Error: dot: can't open tree.dot1`

I am using a windows machine.

Comment: Hi, it seems like a write permission issue. Can you run something like `!touch test.txt` in an empty cell? This will create an empty file in the same directory you are trying to create the .png to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was available in my downloads folder itself.